# Why wouldn't UIView respond to beginAnimations?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

I'm trying to animate adding a new subview to a table view. (When the user clicks on the Plus sign button on the nav bar above the table view, I want a subview with a text field and a button to slide down from under the nav bar).

However, when I try to call `[UIView beginAnimations:@"textFieldSlide", nil]` the compiler warns me that:

> Line Location RootViewController.m:41:
>   warning: 'UIView' may not respond to
>   '+beginAnimations::'

The autocomplete in Xcode also fails to see that method, as well as `commitAnimations`.

Am I missing an import to get these methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to import QuartzCore, UIKit is providing it.

You're using the wrong method signature. You should use

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"textFieldSlide" context:nil];
```

instead.

If Xcode's autocompletion fails, most of the time it is that you've forgot a `]` or a `;` somewhere.